# How to check ajax overlapping and through them out?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I had created a simple on change event in Ajax and trying to get data on the change of select tag [HTML] in another select tag.

All's work fine I got the result on test.php

test.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select name="category" id="category">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Category</option>
            <?php
                include "db-connect/db-connect.php";
                $qry = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `category`");

                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)) {

            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
            <option value="">Choose Sub Category</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the ajax code for this html :-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#category').on('change',function(){
            var categoryID = $(this).val();
            if(categoryID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'ajax/category.php',
                    data:'category_id='+categoryID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#subcategory').html(html);
                        //$('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#subcategory').html('<option value="">Choose category first</option>');
                //$('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

When I run it I got the result but after that, I want to implement it into my project template I got nothing.

But, I get data in the inspect element [F12] -> Network

Ajax data file ajax/category.php:-

```
<?php
//Include the database configuration file xD
include "../db-connect/db-connect.php";
    if(!empty($_POST["category_id"])){
        //Fetch all data
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `sub_category` WHERE `category_id` = ".$_POST['category_id']."");

        //option list
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            echo '<option value="">Select state</option>';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
                echo '<option value="'.$row['sub_category'].'">'.$row['sub_category'].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: did you echo anything inside category.php?and check via console?

Comment: if it's okay then please check db connection

Comment: What do you mean with project template?

Comment: all are okies i had check via console @Shanu k k

Comment: project template means i have a pre-design premium templates @MarkBaijens

Comment: Does that mean your final elements are created dynamically? If so you need to do event delegation. something like `$('#static_parent').on('change', '#category', function(){...});`

Comment: no, my elements are static @MarkBaijens

Comment: please check echo  mysqli_num_rows($query) and check via console.is it greater than 0?

Comment: Yeah! That was greater than 0 @Shanukk

Comment: Do you get any [F12]->Console errors?  Is there `$('#subcategory')` element on the page?

Comment: No, no any error in console there was a only data what I'm fetching in ajaxdata ajax/category.php but i don't getting any elements from there @ourmandave

Comment: Sorry guys there was a problem in my template. Another js fill is reserved SELECT tag properties.